# Retrieve a query string value in C# with .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, regex, query-string

I am working with a C# project that restricts me to .Net 3.5. I need to be able to retrieve the value of a key in a query string that looks something like this: `http://www.test.com/file?id=1&search=search+text&other=stuff`

Without the use of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (doesn't seem to be in .net 3.5) what would be the cleanest way of retrieving a key value?

Side note: I've looked high and low on Google, but can only find examples that make use of the above.

Comment: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` [does exist in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah I've seen that page too. However I've added System.Web to the project and it does not provide anything related to HttpUtility.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing it

1. use: HttpContext.Current.Request["request name here"] (eg. "search")
2. use:

   ```
   Dictionary<string,string> ParseQueryString(string url) {
     if(!url.Contains("?")) return new Dictionary<string,string>();
     var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
     if(url.Contains("&")) {
        var valuekeys = url.Split('?')[1].Split('&');
        foreach(var item in valuekeys) {
           dict.Add(item.Split('=')[0],item.Split('=')[1]);
        }
       return dict;
     } 
     var data = url.Split('?')[1].Split('=');
     dict.Add(data[0],data[1]);
     return dict;
   }
   ```

hope this helps!

// Zerratar

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Request.QueryString("Key")
```

Comment: Is that for a web app? I keep forgetting to say that its a desktop app i'm working on.